# What is the difference

Tags: java, logic, integer-arithmetic

can you tell me the difference between these two logic? First logic solve all question while second logic solve half of the questions? 
Can you tell me where first logic not works?

**First Logic** :

```
        String out = "YES";
        for(int j = 0; j< size-1; j++)
        {
            long difference = Math.abs(array[j+1] - array[j]);
            if(difference > value )
            {
                out = "NO";
                break;
            }     
        }

        System.out.println(out);
```

**Second Logic** :

```
        String out = "NO";
        for(int j = 0; j< size-1; j++)
        {
            long difference = Math.abs(array[j+1] - array[j]);
            if(difference <= value )
            {
                out = "YES";
            }     
            else
            {
               out = "NO";
               break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(out);
```

Here is the question i solved -->

You are given an array of integers and you need to find out if the absolute difference of values of any two consecutive array integers is **at-most D.**

**Input:**
First line of input contains an integer T, denoting the number of test cases. You have to give your output for every test case. 
Every test case contains the size of the array(N), the absolute value difference that you have to check for (D) and the values of the array itself.
First line of each test case contains two integers N and D, denoting the size of the array and value of D respectively.
Second line of each test case contains N integers, which are separated by one space and are the integers for the array.

**Output:**
For each test case, print YES if the absolute difference between any two consecutive integer is at-most D, otherwise print NO.

**Constraints:**
There will not be more than 1000 test cases. Size of the array will also not be greater than 1000 and value of D will be between 1 and 100. The integer values in the array will be between 1 and 106

1 <= T <= 103 
1 <= N <= 103
1 <= D <= 100
1 <= Elements of the array <= 106

first logic solve all the test cases but second logic solve only half of test cases so where first logic failed?

Comment: The second one won't compile.  So there's that.

Comment: What test cases are you talking about? And if you know what tests fail shouldn't you know what the first code is lacking? Thats what test cases are for after all.

Comment: both complied successfully, only difference is that first give solution for all cases while second give solution for only half cases

Comment: Check the output with an empty array. There will be a difference.

Comment: The first one sets the result to "NO" if ONE pair for which difference > value is true. The second one effectively gives you the result for the LAST pair. (Edit: Ok, more likely the first one, depending on your brackets).

Comment: they don't show the testcases.. only you can see is the output of your codes @oh

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz Why? There is a `break` after setting the value to "NO"

Comment: Might be, without correct brackets that's hard to say where it breaks ;-) So I assume the worst.

Comment: You probably have a bad bracket placement near your `else` statement in your second example. BTW, I have no idea why people downvoted this question, as TO showed efforts to solve his problem and came back for help when he faced a bug.

Comment: nope, it's just i write here first time so getting problem with the post, i use both the cases, both compiled successfully and give you output, just first one give right output in all cases while second one give right output in some cases @Nathan

Comment: Maybe you get the difference if you also print out the array values: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));`

Comment: @hEmAnT What is the type of `value`? you may be facing a problem with type comparaison.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these will work, as each will only print a single line (There's only one `System.out.println(out)`, so if there's more than one test case, they will fail.

---

Edited after comments showing that they're running in an external loop.

If there's a single item in the array it will return `"NO"` as that's the default, even though there's no pair with a greater difference.

It might help if we see more of the surrounding code - is `size` set correctly for each test case?

Comment: @david The code pasted iterates on **one** of the testcase array. The code is probably in a for loop that iterates on the tests cases